# How to save a python script directly from python shell?

Tags: python

Currently, I am working on python interactive shell version 6. When i start python shell, i use to code some line. but i don't know how to store what i code. So, is there any command or or keyword to save my session on python shell as like .py

Comment: What is "python interactive shell version 6"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you mean [ipython](http://ipython.org)? For this shell, all your input is stored in the `In` dictionary. Here's an example session log how to write input lines 2-3 into the script `myscript.py`:

```
Python 2.7.1 |EPD 7.0-2 (32-bit)| (r271:86832, Nov 29 2010, 13:52:51) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 0.10.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object'. ?object also works, ?? prints more.

In [2]: print "Hello world."
Hello world.

In [3]: print "Hello world again."
Hello world again.

In [4]: fid = open("myscript.py", "w")

In [5]: for i in range(2,4):
   ...:     fid.write(In[i])
   ...: 

In [6]: fid.close()

In [7]: run myscript.py
Hello world.
Hello world again.
```

Comment: Thank you! your response for my doubt is very useful!

Answer (score 1):

Not clear on exactly what you're asking and I don't know what you mean by "version 6"....

But if you are in IDLE (meaning when you open the shell it looks something like this):

```
Python 2.7 (r27:82525, Jul  4 2010, 09:01:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>>
```

You can either create a new window (File --> New or Ctrl-N on Windows) and save your file from there.

You can also use an editor instead of IDLE (emacs, Notepad++, vim, etc.) and save your file from there.

If you just want to keep a log of your shell activity (not an executable script) you can also save from IDLE's file menu.

Comment: Excuse me! i have told that the version of python package to install! the example you have shown is python version 7, that means 2.7. So my python version is 6, that means 2.6

Comment: Well, 2.7 is not that much different from 2.6.  The above instructions should still work for you.